# Passing multiple data values through AJAX data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am passing data from a form through a normal AJAX call. What I need to do now is pass two additional variables through it `elat` and `elng`

What is the best method to include `filter.serialize()` and `elat` `elng` values through AJAX data?

```
    var elat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var elng = place.geometry.location.lng();

    var filter = $('#filter');

    $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), //Pass [elat] and [elng] through here too.
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is #filter element?

Comment: @Ahmad it's input/select fields taken from a form. Wasn't sure if it's relevant for question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually concatenate to the string produced by `filter.serialize()`

```
data:filter.serialize() + '&elat=' + elat + '&elng=' + elng,
```

Or add hidden inputs to the form before serializing.

```
filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elat'}).val(elat));
filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elng'}).val(elng));
```

Comment: Perfect, went with the hidden input approach. Keeps it more organised! Thanks.